# python de bucle for a xml

Tags: python, xml, loops

tengo un archivo donde con una expresion regular saco 3 datos que se pueden repetir hasta 30 veces

```
matches = tools.findall(pattern, html, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:

    pattern = 'umber\":(.*?),\"g'
    dato1 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\],\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"ov'
    dato2 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\"overview\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"id'
    dato3 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]
```

mi intension es con esos datos generar un xml de la siguiente forma:

```
<root>
    <item>
       <nombre>dato1</nombre>
       <direccion>dato2</direccion>
       <telefono>dato3</telefono>
    </item>
    <item>
       <nombre>dato1</nombre>
       <direccion>dato2</direccion>
       <telefono>dato3</telefono>
    </item>
    <item>
       <nombre>dato1</nombre>
       <direccion>dato2</direccion>
       <telefono>dato3</telefono>
    </item>
<root>
```

los items quiero que se repitan cuantos datos se recojan del bucle for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla si entendí lo que preguntabas es componer manualmente el xml de la siguiente forma

```
matches = tools.findall(pattern, html, re.MULTILINE)
xml_text = "<root>"
for match in matches:

    pattern = 'umber\":(.*?),\"g'
    dato1 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\],\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"ov'
    dato2 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\"overview\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"id'
    dato3 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    xmltext = xmltext + "  <item>\n     <nombre>{0}</nombre>\n     <direccion>{1}</direccion>\n     <telefono>{2}</telefono>\n  </item>\n".format(dato1, dato2, dato3)

xml_text = xml_text + "</root>"
print(xml_text)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, la verdad no se porque no me funciono el metodo de ejemplo que pones arriba , pero al final gracias a tu idea logre esto y realizo lo que queria.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la libreria xml, para este proceso en especifico utiliza `xml.etree.ElementTree`

genera  tu elemnto principal con:

```
root = ElementTree.Element("root")
```

luego agregas los subelementos con

```
ElementTree.SubElement(root, 'nombre').text='dato1'
```

finalmente generas el xml con

```
ElementTree.dump(root)
```

el ejemplo completo quedaría así:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

root = ElementTree.Element('root')

matches = tools.findall(pattern, html, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:      


    pattern = 'umber\":(.*?),\"g'
    dato1 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\],\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"ov'
    dato2 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    pattern = '\"overview\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"id'
    dato3 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

    item=ElementTree.SubElement(root, 'item')
    ElementTree.SubElement(item, 'nombre').text='dato1'
    ElementTree.SubElement(item, 'direccion').text='dato2'
    ElementTree.SubElement(item, 'telefono').text='dato3'

ElementTree.dump(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

codigo  que  hizo la funcion.

```
for match in matches:
pattern = 'umber\":(.*?),\"g'
dato1 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

pattern = '\],\"name\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"ov'
dato2 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

pattern = '\"overview\"\:\"(.*?)\",\"id'
dato3 = tools.findall(pattern, match, re.MULTILINE)[0]

xmltext = "  <item>\n     <nombre>{0}</nombre>\n     <direccion>{1}</direccion>\n     <telefono>{2}</telefono>\n  </item>\n".format(
    dato1, dato2, dato3)

fichero = open ( 'filename.xml', 'a' )
fichero.write(xmltext)
```